# Is this electric field formula deduction correct?

Tags: electric-fields, voltage

I had found the formula
$-\int_{B}^{A}\overrightarrow{E}\vec{\mathrm d\ell}=\Delta V$ in my physics book and I wondered how to get the electric field formula out of this equation. So, I proceeded to try to differentiate both sides and get to a conclusion:

$\frac{\mathrm d(-\int_{B}^{A}\overrightarrow{E}\vec{\mathrm d\ell})}{\vec{\mathrm d\ell}}=\frac{\mathrm d(\Delta V)}{\vec{\mathrm d\ell}}$

$\overrightarrow{E}=\frac{\mathrm d^2 V}{\vec{\mathrm d\ell}}$

$\overrightarrow{E}=-\frac{\mathrm d^2 V}{\vec{\mathrm d\ell}}$

Comment: Note that you have to remember that there are dot product in there. The potential is a scalar, and both the E field and the small displacement step are not scalars.

Comment: True that, I assume that's why you cannot simplify the derivative of a differential to a double derivative.

Comment: There are double derivatives, but you misunderstood the notation at the top. The $\Delta V$ is just the $V(B)-V(A)$ and you really only have first derivative, not second.

Comment: My answer below is equivalent to saying that $\vec E=-\frac{\mathrm dV}{\vec{\mathrm d\ell}}$, and it would be a correct notation, if a bit clumsy. We don't like the vector arrow in the denominator, because it will be too busy to read easily.

Comment: And what difference is there from that to $\vec{E}=-\frac{d (\Delta  V)}{\vec{d \ell}}$? Do we just simplify $\Delta  V$ to $V$?

Comment: Yes, because you confused two different uses of $\Delta$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you needed to write the equation out in higher detail. In the following, to easily visualise how the directions would be aligned, let $A$ have a higher potential than $B$ so that the electric field is pointing from $A$ to $B:$
\begin{align}
\tag1V(A)-V(B)&=\int_A^B\vec E\cdot\vec{\mathrm d\ell}\\
\tag2V(A)-V(B+\delta B)&=\int_A^{B+\delta B}\vec E\cdot\vec{\mathrm d\ell}\\
\tag3-\left[V(B+\delta B)-V(B)\right]&=\int_B^{B+\delta B}\vec E\cdot\vec{\mathrm d\ell}=\vec E\cdot\vec{\delta B}\\
\tag4\vec E&=-\frac{V(B+\delta B)-V(B)}{\vec{\delta B}}\\
\tag5\vec E&=-\vec{\nabla V}
\end{align}
This last formula is actually the usual definition of the electrostatic potential.

Comment: Wouldn't equation $(3)$ be: $-[V(B+\delta B)-V(A)]=\int_B^{B+\delta B}\vec E\cdot\vec{\mathrm d\ell}=\vec E\cdot\vec{\delta B} \ $? Or what relationship does equation $(2)$ and $(3)$ have then? The substitution of $A:=B \ $?

Comment: Equation (3) is Equation (2) minus Equation (1). You can definitely just have Equation (1) and do a substitution, say of A = B-delta B.

Comment: Understood now, that's why the limits of integration change as well. What I still do not comprehend is equation $(4)$ to equation $(5)$. How does one define $-\nabla \overrightarrow{V}$ as all of that? Is it simply the multivariable derivative ($\nabla$: nabla operator) definition?

Comment: Yes. In 1D it is $\vec{\nabla V}=\dfrac{\mathrm dV}{\mathrm dx}$. In extremely full detail, each direction vector $\vec n$ you get a directional derivative $\vec n\cdot\vec{\nabla V}$ by simple old calculus, and if, and only if, there is a fixed $\vec{\nabla V}$ that for all directions $\vec n$ the directional derivative is given by the dotting formula, then you can differentiate by the components of the direction vector $\vec n$ and obtain $\vec{\nabla V}$ as a uniquely well-defined one-form.

Comment: Understood it a bit better then, thank you very much for the explanation!